# line wrapping after calling command

Tags: ls

I am calling `ls` from a bash script and filtering the results (a learning process for my self)

I get the results but they are all on separate lines (because I echoed them using a while read line) so I then added all the results to an array and printed them.

The line wrapping is awful, I am trying to make the out put look identical to the `ls` output, how would I go about this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to print the elements of an array in columns like `ls` does?

Comment: See also: [How can a space-delimited list of words be folded into tabular columns that fit in the terminal's width](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/324275)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ahh ok thank you, I shall look at this... columns would make sense now you say it. although I am looking for something that does not require extra packages as answers in that link suggest